# Django Query Get all User Items from my Accounts

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to figure out the best (simplest) ways to call all the "Items" from my different User "Accounts."

The Account has the User ForeignKey.

```
class Acct ( models.Model ):
    user = models.ForeignKey ( settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

The Item has the Account foreignKey.

```
class Items ( models.Model ):
    acct = models.ForeignKey ( Acct )
```

So when I have a list of Acct's - what is the best way to get all the User's Items for the different accounts?

I can get all the Accounts with something like this:

```
a = request.user.acct_set.all ().filter ( active = 1 )
```

Now what is the next call to get the Items for those Accounts?

Only thing I can figure out is to add the User foreignKey to the Items also. (I would also have to add the Active field.)

I hope this makes sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add any more foreign keys - you can just [traverse the existing relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) directly in one query like so:

```
# Fetch all the items associated with all accounts for this user
items = Item.objects.filter(acct__active=1, acct__user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is most efficient method, but it seems to be working.

```
id = request.user.acct_set.values_list ( 'id', flat=True ).filter ( active = 1 )

items = Item.objects.filter ( acct__in = id ) .order_by ( 'date' )
```

If there is a better way I would appreciate knowing it.

Thanks.